# xCode auto-layout different on 5 and 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

[image]

I have a calculator display in my app that uses auto layout. The iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s have the same display and resolution; however, when I run the app in the simulator the iPhone 5 displays it far poorer than the iPhone 5s. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone? it's common issue with autolayout.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more?

Comment: i've added answer with more deailed explanations

Comment: have you used size classes ?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot see your constraints it is difficult for me to give you a definite answer. This is what I would do.

1. select the text field that is mis aligned
2. click on the far left triangle between two pikes icon.
3. click on clear constraints.
4. a. rest to suggested constraints  -or- 
   b. control drag to the sides and create your own constraints
   [image: what to do]

Comment: I had given that a shot, but I still had no luck. The constraints have no errors. They seem to be entirely right in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

According to this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

> To adjust how a view controller lays out its views, UIViewController
>   provides the following properties:
>
> edgesForExtendedLayout: The edgesForExtendedLayout property uses the
>   UIRectEdge type, which specifies each of a rectangle’s four edges, in
>   addition to specifying none and all. Use edgesForExtendedLayout to
>   specify which edges of a view should be extended, regardless of bar
>   translucency. By default, the value of this property is UIRectEdgeAll.

Try to set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;`